# disable entering to enable mode IOS

Tags: cisco-ios

Is it possible to disable entering an enable mode on IOS ?
Im deploying radius servers with two user groups (lvl 1 and lvl 15) my goal is to do that users who are lvl 1 would be not permited to enter enable mode.
Yes, i know i can create a password for enable mode. But maybe it's possible to even not to let the enter that mode for level 1 users ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable enable command in any privilege level because it is used to login from privilige level to higher level . 
as per  Cisco IOS Security Configuration Guide, Release 12.2:

By default, the Cisco IOS software command-line interface (CLI) has two levels of access to commands: user EXEC mode (level 1) and privileged EXEC mode (level 15). However, you can configure additional levels of access to commands, called privilege levels, to meet the needs of your users while protecting the system from unauthorized access. Up to 16 privilege levels can be configured, from level 0, which is the most restricted level, to level 15, which is the least restricted level